# how to check if values in multiple columns are under a certain number?

Tags: sas

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
ID  C1  C2  C3  C4....C50
A   23  0   50  0......4
B   10  0   0   0......1
```

The goal is to check if any of the columns: c1-c50 has a value under 20 for each ID.  I used this code but it doesn't give me the accurate flag variable.

```
data want;
set have;
array c c1-c50;
min_num=0;
do i=1 to 50;
if c[i] < 20 then flag=0; else flag=1;
end;
drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ditch the `else`.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array c c1-c50;
  min_num=0;
  flag = 0;
  do i=1 to 50;
    if c[i] ge 20 then flag=1;
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

That will start it at 0, and then if any of them are 20 or over set it to 1.  If missing is a possibility and you don't want that to count as under 20, check for that separately, as `.<20` is true (missing is the smallest number so less than everything).

---

Of course, you could just use `max`...

```
data want;
  set have;
  flag = (max(of c1-c50) < 20) = 0;
run;
```